# Use React state to manage list of already instanced objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js

I want to check each collection I instance to see if another instance of the same type already exists so I can use the stored version instead of creating a new one, how can I use the react state to keep a list to check against?

**Sample code:**

```
export default React.createBackboneClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            data: [],
            groups: {}
        }
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            data: this.props.collection
        });
    },

    render() {
        const gridGroups = this.state.data.map((model) => {

            let gridGroupsCollection = null;

            if(this.state.groups[model.get('id')]) {
                gridGroupsCollection = this.state.groups[model.get('id')];
            } else {
                gridGroupsCollection = this.state.groups[model.get('id')] = new GridGroupCollection([], {
                    groupId: model.get('id')
                });

                this.setState((previous) => {
                    groups: _.extend({}, previous, gridGroupsCollection)
                });
            }

            return <GridGroupComponent
                key={model.get('id')}
                name={model.get('n')}
                collection={gridGroupsCollection} />
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {gridGroups}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points. First of all, I would use the componentWillReviewProps to do the heavy work. Doing so on the **render** method can be more costly. I have yet to save instances on the state object. Is it needed for caching performance-wise or to solve a sorting issue?

Moreover, as noted already, calling setState from the render method will generate an infinite loop. as render is called when the state changes.

On a side note I would consider [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) for this, which offers several holistic ways to separate components from data manipulation.

**update**

[This TodoMVC example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react-backbone/js/app.jsx) might point you to the direction of how to combine react and backbone:

```
 componentDidMount: function () {
        // Whenever there may be a change in the Backbone data, trigger a
        // reconcile.
        this.getBackboneCollections().forEach(function (collection) {
            // explicitly bind `null` to `forceUpdate`, as it demands a callback and
            // React validates that it's a function. `collection` events passes
            // additional arguments that are not functions
            collection.on('add remove change', this.forceUpdate.bind(this, null));
        }, this);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        // Ensure that we clean up any dangling references when the component is
        // destroyed.
        this.getBackboneCollections().forEach(function (collection) {
            collection.off(null, null, this);
        }, this);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but I get errors due to setting state in render - warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: This is expected as calling setState in the render method will start an infinite loop. Render is automatically called when the state changes so if you change the state in the render method you start an infinite loop.

Comment: Hey, how would I fix this is what this.getCachedGridGroupCollection is basically doing?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by creating new instances of GridGroupCollection. Is it a React component?

Comment: Hey, yeah I think I need to move my collection logic out to a data layer. Just confused by combining react and backbone right now. Thanks for your advice!!

Comment: Sure thing @styler, added a code snippet that might help. Good coding.